# Copy snapshot artifact from nexus without pom

Tags: maven, maven-dependency-plugin

I want to download a snapshot artifact using the `dependecy.copy` target. I don't want to have a POM file.

```
mvn -U dependency:copy -Dartifact=mygroupId:myArtifactId:myversion-SNAPSHOT:jar
```

Unfortunately this only works if the artifact is already in the local maven repo cache. When it's not in the maven cache I get the following error:

```
Unable to find artifact.
...
foo-public (https://nexus.foo.org/content/groups/public-foo/, releases=true, snapshots=false)
```

It says foo-public because I'm using a `settings.xml`

```
<mirror>
  <id>foo</id>
  <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
  <name>My Maven Nexus Repository</name>
  <url>http://nexus.foo.org/content/groups/public-foo/</url>
</mirror>
```

The reason seems to be that [Maven's Super POM](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html#Super_POM) has set snapshots=false for the central repo. If I add a minimalistic `pom.xml` to the working directory I don't have the error as snapshots=true seems to be the default for any other repo.

```
<project>
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>dummy</groupId>
    <artifactId>dummy</artifactId>
    <version>1</version>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>dummy</id>
            <url>dummy</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
</project>
```

My current work around is to write the dummy POM before calling my mvn command. Another possible work around is to add the following to `settings.xml` ([Found in Sonatype nexus book](http://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/2.8/reference/maven-sect-single-group.html))

```
<profiles>
  <profile>
    <id>nexus</id>
    <!--Enable snapshots for the built in central repo to direct -->
    <!--all requests to nexus via the mirror -->
    <repositories>
      <repository>
        <id>central</id>
        <url>http://central</url>
        <releases><enabled>true</enabled></releases>
        <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
      </repository>
    </repositories>
 </profile>
</profiles>
<activeProfiles>
  <!--make the profile active all the time -->
  <activeProfile>nexus</activeProfile>
</activeProfiles>
```

Do you have a more elegant idea that works without so much preparation? For instance a command line switch?

Comment: Ever thought to use `curl`?

Comment: @khmarbaise That's what I replaced with mvn dependency plugin. I had to specify credentials which I don't want to store in my filesystem.

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to use [`dependency:get`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/get-mojo.html) goal instead of [`dependeny:copy`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/copy-mojo.html) goal, see [Apache Maven Dependency Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/usage.html):

> **The dependency:get Mojo**
>
> This mojo is used to fetch an artifact and (optionally) its dependencies from remote repositories using its Maven coordinates.
>
> ```
>  mvn dependency:get -DgroupId=org.apache.maven -DartifactId=maven-core -Dversion=2.2.1 -Dpackaging=jar -Dclassifier=sources -DremoteRepositories=central::default::http://repo1.maven.apache.org/maven2,myrepo::::http://myrepo.com/maven2
>  mvn dependency:get -DgroupId=org.apache.maven -DartifactId=maven-core -Dversion=2.2.1 -Dpackaging=jar -Dclassifier=sources -DremoteRepositories=http://repo1.maven.apache.org/maven2 
>  mvn dependency:get -Dartifact=org.apache.maven:maven-core:2.2.1:jar:sources -DremoteRepositories=http://repo1.maven.apache.org/maven2 -Ddest=/tmp/myfile.jar
> ```

Your modified command:

```
mvn dependency:get -U -DgroupId=mygroupId -DartifactId=myArtifactId -Dversion=myversion-SNAPSHOT -Dpackaging=jar -Dtransitive=false -s settings.xml -DremoteRepositories=https://nexus.foo.org/content/groups/public-foo/ -Ddest=target/myArtifactId.jar
```

Comment: Meanwhile the "dest" argument is deprecated. The solution is to call "dependency:get" which downloads the artifact to the local repository. Then call "dependency:copy" to copy it from the local repo to the place where you need it. However "dependency:copy" does not work for artifacts that have no pom.xml .... wonderful maven world :-/